# Clear TextBox and update DataGrid from ObvservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am using the MVVM pattern to write a WPF application. I created the UI using a TabControl. In one tab I have a list of clients in my company and in the other tab I have a form which is used to add new clients. I want two things:

1. Adding new client --> new position on the list when the tab with clients is pressed
2. Clearing form TextBoxes after adding a client

Neither of them works.

My DataGrid part:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource ClientsVM}">
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="pack://application:,,,/Insurance company;component/Resources/logo.png" Height="100" Margin="5,15,0,0"/>
    <DataGrid  Name="ClientsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="130,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="101">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client ID" Binding="{Binding ClientId}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PESEL" Binding="{Binding PESEL}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ClientsGridLeftDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ClientsGrid, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Part of my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<ClientSet> _clients;

public ObservableCollection<ClientSet> Clients
{
    get { return _clients; }
    set
    {
        if (_clients != value)
        {
            _clients = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => "Clients");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, doing something like:

```
_clients = new ObservableCollection<ClientSet>(updatedListOfClientsHere);
```

doesn't work. Why not?

The other thing is with clearing the form. It looks like this:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" FontSize="15">Surname</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="141" Name="Surname" Text="{Binding Client.Surname, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" FontSize="15">Name</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="141" Name="Name" Text="{Binding Client.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

And the values typed by the user are properly reflected in the ViewModel class. But if I clear them in the ViewModel - nothing happens in the UI. Part of my ViewModel here:

```
private ClientSet _client;

public ClientSet Client
{
    get { return _client; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _client)
        {
            _client = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => "Client");
        };
    }
}

// Some code

// Clearing the form:
_client = new ClientSet(); // This shouldn't work?
Client.Name = string.empty; // This should work!!!
```

I am really out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed a few problems from your question. First, calling the private member of *any* property in a view model should only be done when you *don't want the UI to update*. If you want the UI to update, then you *have to* use the public properties, because that is what notifies the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (through your `RaisePropertyChanged` method). So to clear the client list, just call:

```
Clients = new ObservableCollection<ClientSet>(updatedListOfClientsHere);
```

Next, I don't know for sure because you didn't show your `ClientSet` class, but I'm guessing that you didn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in it. However, you are still expecting property changes of that class to be updated... they won't unless you either implement it in that class, or wrap each property in your view model and call your `RaisePropertyChanged` method from there. Then, calling `Client.Name = string.empty;` will clear that field.

Comment: That was the problem... I was updating private properties, changed them to public and everything worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but lets see:

First, with your observable collection, you don't need to set it again. If you create a new Client, all you need to do is :

```
Clients.Add(new_client_object);
```

That's all. Otherwise, if it takes a while to create the clients, your program will get slower (I've seen this happen, trust me ...)

If I understand correctly, you want to clear the items in the add new client after you add it. All you need to do here is make sure the content control (hopefully your add client view is a usercontrol or something like that) receives an object of type client, and after you add it, just set it to null, or put a new (empty) object, or set them manually to empty strings (Be sure to have a a backup in case you want to cancel, or that you don't overwrite your new client fields).

You could add some screenshots to clarify what you want/need.

Comment: The thing is I am not sure how can I pass Clients object to the AddClientViewModel from the ClientsModel (this is how it is solved in my application). 

As far as clearing the form is concerned, what you suggest is what I tried to do. TextBoxes Text property is bound to Client.Name, Client.Surname etc... And in the ViewModel (after adding a new client) i do Client = new ClientSet() which should clear the form, shouldn't it? It does nothing...

Comment: You could either call them directly using the method (if you have a Locator), or use Messaging otherwise. Any other references to that object? Also, why is it called ClientSet? (it suggests it might be a set/collection). Last, does this object implements INotifyPropertyChanged(so other objects will know it changed) ?

Comment: The name ClientSet is stupid, you're right. This is the name that the Entity Framework created for me... Yes, it does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Clicking twice on a position in a clients DataGrid opens en edit form for a client and changes made there are immediately reflected in the list. There is just this problem with zeroing the form...

Comment: I'll try to add this Locator to fix the issue with updating clients collection.

Comment: I assume the binding in a TextBox Text property should be TwoWay?

Comment: Yep, so whatever you type goes to object, and if it changes, it's reflected on the GUI (hence, 2 way :)

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I honestly have no idea why clearing this form is not working... Binding is TwoWay and change in the UI is reflected in the VM but changing in the VM is not reflected in the UI...